# GUI mode not loading

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a HP ENVY 15z with Windows 8 pre-installed, and I've set part of the HDD for Linux, so I have Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 in dualboot. Problem is, Ubuntu no longer boots, Windows boots just fine but Ubuntu either boots into terminal or to a black screen.

Comment: what graphic card you are using  ? I mean VGA drivers installed ? lspci | grep VGA

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to re-install the drivers for your graphics card.

Next time you boot into Ubuntu, switch to a new TTY using ctrl+alt+F2. Log in with your username and password, then attempt to start the X server.

```
$ sudo startx
```

If it doesn't work then run this and then reboot:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.orig /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

If you get an error then run

```
$ sudo ls -l /etc/X11/xorg.*
```

and copy the old xorg config file over xorg.conf

If this doesn't fix it then reply with the output you receive to the commands above. And also to:

```
$ sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'
```

and:

```
$ glxinfo -i | grep render
```